# pyglet requires an X server with GLX

Tags: raspberry-pi

When I try to run my Front end application file "Frontend.py" which outputs a GUI Information screen

I get following error, Even I installed everything "PyProcessing,Pyglet" all the necessary utilities for my application successfully

but I am getting this

```
"File "MIISC_Frontend.py", line 18, in <module>
from pyprocessing import __draw
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyprocessing-0.1.3.22-py2.7.egg/pyprocessing/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
from pyglet.gl import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 510, in <module>
import pyglet.window
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1684, in <module>
gl._create_shadow_window()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 494, in _create_shadow_window
_shadow_window = Window(width=1, height=1, visible=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 474, in __init__
super(XlibWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 636, in __init__
config = screen.get_best_config(template_config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 288, in get_best_config
configs = self.get_matching_configs(template)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 238, in get_matching_configs
have_13 = self.display.info.have_version(1, 3)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/gl/glx_info.py", line 79, in have_version
raise GLXInfoException('pyglet requires an X server wit
```

h GLX')

```
pyglet.gl.glx_info.GLXInfoException: pyglet requires an X server with GLX""
```

Plz help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's great that you posted the full error message, but can you also post the (relevant) code that causes this error? Otherwise we can't help you change it to make it work... :)

Comment: Please edit your question to tag it properly. This has nothing to do with [google-chrome-extension]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyglet appears to require GLX.  This error means the display pyglet is talking to doesn't have GLX.

1. Is your DISPLAY set correctly?  Usually this will be `:0`  Try:

   echo $DISPLAY
2. Does your X server not support GLX? Try:

   `xdpyinfo | grep GLX`

If that really comes up empty then check your X startup log (e.g. on Linux)

```
grep -i glx /var/log/Xorg*
```

Some VNC servers will not provide GLX.  You can fake it using the VirtualGL package.

Comment: Actually I am using Raspberry Pi , and I installed all the basic utilities properly.

Like my code work fine on Windows eclipse.

But when I try to execute it on Raspberry Pi linux platform it throw this error.

Is pyglet compatible with Rasp PI

Comment: Apparently the Pi currently only supports OpenGL ES (so no GLX), but that may change since Eric Anholt is now [working on better drivers](http://anholt.livejournal.com/44239.html)

Comment: BTW, [this question/answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3285/sdl-couldnt-find-matching-glx-visual) suggests installing the software renderer as a work-around.  AKA `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-swx11`

Comment: This answer in comments helped me a lot and resolved this issue. Thanks Nathan.